# Formula for non-linear graph. The further you slide, the less it moves

Tags: c#, formula, nonlinear-functions

There's a name for a graph that does this, and I am trying to figure out an algorithm that calculates a result based on a DOUBLE input.

Like this: 
https://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/Algebra1/COURSE_TEXT_RESOURCE/U03_L2_T5_text_final_files/image008.gif

I am trying to create a method that accomplishes what you see in apps that basically slows down velocity the further you pull. So for instance, if you slide your finger, a box appears easily, but then the further you pull, the slower it moves.

The full requirement is to have a "free pull" amount, i.e.: it's a 1:1 relationship where the amount you slide your finger, the output value is that much as well. And have a theoretical "max result", which I assume is theoretical, because the more your finger moves, the smaller the amount changes by.

I have a feeling there is a formula for this. So any Maths guys, please help :)

Comment: Google "exponential decay"--i have a feeling itll fit your request.

Comment: The graph provided looks like `v = a / t` (*hyperbolic*); if you're looking for more elaborated solution, e.g. `v = a / t**1.234 + b/t**2.345` you have to provide some points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to try and see which formula works best for you.

Let's say the length of a finger pull is `D` and the distance of how far the box moves is `D'`. You can start with something very simple, like:

```xml
D' = D / 2
```

Then if you need some "free pull" distance of `F`, you would probably include it like this:

```xml
D' = if D < F
     then D
     else F + (D - F) / 2
```

To see which behavior of `D'` works best, you'll need to try different formulas. For example, a square root:

```xml
D' = if D < F
     then D
     else F + sqrt(D - F)
```

**Edit:** Here's a version with an upper boundary of `F + M`. It works because arctan's upper asymptote is `Pi/2`.

```xml
D' = if D < F
     then D
     else F + arctan((D - F) / M) * M * (2 / Pi)
```

[**Sample graph for F = 5, M = 3**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%2C+x+%3C%3D+5%7D%2C+%7B5%2Barctan%28%28x-5%29%2F3%29*3*2%2FPi%2C+x+%3E%3D+5%7D%7D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+30%7D%5D).
`D'` will never reach `8` in this example.

Comment: First off, this looks exactly what I want (the one with Square Root), but any idea how to set a theoretical max, so that I can make it move more or less than the default SQRT output?

Comment: @KrisAdams take a look at my last example. The box will never move further than `F + M`. Or do you want the SQRT behavior with added max distance?

Comment: Your formula for including the theoretical max doesn't seem to work correctly. It goes to the "free pull" amount fine, but then accelerates very quickly. It would ideally need to be seamless from the free amount up to the theoretical max.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as the accepted answer for the SQRT formula though. That's the one I am going to use: D' = if D < F then D else F + sqrt(D - F)

Comment: @KrisAdams yeah, sorry, I screwed up somewhere in the max. distance formula. If you want, I can still look into it later.

Comment: For anyone else who looks at the question (any myself) that would be helpful if you have time later to figure out how to get it perfect. But the SQRT answer is great anyway!

Comment: @KrisAdams added another formula with a working upper boundary.